# QtCreator: How to keep inspecting variables in certain stack frame level when debugging (C++)?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I'm having trouble with debugging C++ code using QtCreator.

As you can see, here is a very simple recursion in C++:

[image: example code]

When trying to debug this code, I wanna keep inspecting the elements in "sorted" and "unsorted". However, QtCreator automatically shows the variables in the topmost stack frame when recursion goes on. Like this (see the small pane on the right):

[image: variables on the topmost stack frame]

If I wanna see the elements in "sorted" and "unsorted", I have to double-click the "Main()" function in stack pane. And every time the recursion goes on, it goes back to the topmost stack frame and shows information not helpful for me. I have to do that again to see the variables I want. Is there any way that I can keep inspecting the variables I want? Like "sorted" and "unsorted", which are not the variable of the "topmost stack frame", at the right pane in the picture below:

[image: variables that I wanna keep tracking which are not on the topmost stack frame]

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think, if these vectors passed by reference, they will be same everywhere?

Comment: @Serhiy Yes, I think so. But as you can see in the second picture I posted, the QtCreator just left those vector value empty in the "Locals & Expression Window(upper right)". I have to double-click the "Main()" function on the "Stack Window (bottom left)", then I can see the values in those variables in the "Locals & Expression Window" like it appears in picture 3...

Comment: @Serhiy If I use Xcode to debug this, everything is fine. But I wanna know how to fix this in Qt...